# Short layover in Heathrow

Tags: transit, lhr

British Airways (BA) just changed our flight times, leaving us only 1h15mins for our layover in Heathrow.
We arrive from Brussels in terminal 5 in Heathrow at 7:55 and our next flight leaves for Miami in Heathrow terminal 3 at 9:10.

This seems awfully short.

Does anyone know whether this is doable?

The flights are in November, so I'm still hoping that the flights will change back to the original flight times, which would give us an additional hour for the layover, but in case this does not happen, what are the chances that we will make the connecting flight in 1h15mins?

Comment: Yes, it's part of a single booking. Not sure what you mean with carrier?

Comment: Ah, yes, all flights are with BA (Brussels>Heathrow and Heathrow>Miami)

Comment: Okay, many thanks for the reassurance. I'm freaking out a bit when reading these horrible stories about the lines at security. Good to know it's BA's responsibility to look after us. Hopefully all will go smoothly.

Comment: Ah, okay, let's hope it will only take a few minutes. I'll definitely try to report back :)

Comment: If you miss your flight due to BA's first flight being late, it's their job to get you to Miami at their expense. Looking at the flight schedules for November, there are 3 more BA / AA flights from Heathrow to Miami within the next few hours after yours, so if your flight from Brussels is late, it will only mean getting to Miami a few hours later. Don't worry!

Comment: Be aware that the BA computers that handle flight schedule changes are different to the BA computers that spot invalid connections. It'll take a few days for them to notice that the rescheduled flight is now too soon, and come up with a new plan that is more sensible. You can ring them in the mean time to speed the process up if you want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to British Airways, [it depends on the terminal](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/airport-information/london-heathrow-airport/lhr-connections). Check that page for more information.

> ### Flight connections with British Airways at London Heathrow
>
> The flight connections process within Heathrow airport will vary depending on
>   your origin and final destination. When you arrive at Heathrow, please
>   follow the purple ‘Flight Connections’ signs (as shown to the right),
>   which will lead you to your next flight.
>
> We recommend that you allow the following minimum connection times:
>
> - 60 – 70 minutes for connections within the same Heathrow terminal.
> - 90 minutes for connections that require travel between terminals at
>     Heathrow.
>
> You must be at the gate for your onward journey at least 20
>   minutes before your connecting flight departs, so please ensure you
>   allow plenty of time, for example if you need to collect your bags or
>   require additional support getting through the airport.

As others have mentioned in the comments, you have booked your flights as a single booking with BA, so it is their responsibility to get you to your final destination.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed checked the page information on connecting flights and it said that our connection time was under the minimum connection time and that we should contact a BA responsible, which, of course, I will do first thing tomorrow morning. I hope everything will work out, I'll be nervous about this till November :)

Comment: @Dorien When you arrive at Heathrow, if your flight isn't _very_ early, let a flight attendant and/or a staff member at the arrival gate know that you have a very short connection and ask for help with making it. Having to schedule you on a later flight is disruptive for them as well as you, so they will try to get you on the connection if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Short update: we decided to have our flights changed and now have over 3 hours to make the connection. This will give us more peace of mind, I really don't like stressing over connection times when travelling :)

Because it's an involuntary change due to BA's decision to change the flight times, we're not even charged any additional fees.